# laravel collect function is undefined

Tags: php, laravel

i am getting data from database which in need to group so i am converting database result set in to array and then passing it to laravel collect helper but i gives me error

```
Call to undefined function collect()
```

Code

```
  $user_profile=collect(UserProfileItem::where('type', "age_group")->get()->toArray())->groupBy("age_group");
```

please help me about what i am doing wrong i want to use laravel collections method groupby to group my database result array by "age_group"

like below data group by **account_id**

```
 [
        'account-x10' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'account-x11' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: where is the collect function supposed to be defined?

Comment: if i am calling collect function like this collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]); still getting same error that  Call to undefined function collect()

Comment: you don't need the collect function. the query itself is the collection.

Comment: Did you use the correct namespace?

Comment: what it should be

Comment: yes i am using this

Comment: like use App\Helpers; perhaps. You can check your config file for aliases

Comment: not working gettting error Call to undefined function collect()

Comment: what i need to add in config aliases array tell me please

Comment: do you have a `use App\Helpers;` or similar import ?

Comment: Why don't you try like this  `$user_profile=collect(UserProfileItem::where('type', "age_group")->groupBy("age_group")->get()->toArray());` Can you tell me why you need to use collect method?

Comment: – ikdekker no i dont have

Comment: rahulsm 2 if i do this sql query group by will be run

Comment: which laravel version you are using??

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to add collect function as you are already getting a collection. So you need to do it as :

```
$user_profile = UserProfileItem::where('type', "age_group")->get()->groupBy("age_group");
```

Comment: Pooja Yengandul when using this instead of array returned object is grouping :(

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed you can convert it to array by appending toArray() on groupBy().

Answer (score 1):

you need to first get the groups and loop through them and add data in those to the collection

```
$groups = UserProfileItem::groupBy("age_group")->get();
$collection = collect();

foreach($groups as $group){
  $data = UserProfileItem::where('type', $group->type)->get();

  $collection->put($group->type , $data);
}

return $collection;
```

Comment: Chamara Abeysekara you means query in loop ??

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: by calling get function inside loop your are executing query inside loop which is a bad solution for load testing

Comment: yes but for the structure you need can not be achieved with out looping

Comment: so i think i will go with one server side loop to group data instead of hitting database query many time

Answer (score 0):

i think for previous version of laravel creating your own group is the only solution

```
   public function getGroupedUser($group="age_group"){

        $users = $this->users->keyBy('id')->toArray();
        $user_profile=UserProfileItem::where('type', "age_group")->get()->groupBy("age_group");
        foreach ($user_profile as $row){
            $urow[$row['data']][]=$row;
        }
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user_profile);die;
    }
```